# SQL Oracle, inserting into tables without sequence

Tags: sql

I am working with an Oracle 11.2g instance.
I'd like to know what I am exposing to by inserting rows into tables by generating the primary key values myself. 
I would SELECT max(pk) FROM sometables;
and then use the next hundred values for example for my next 100 inserts.
Is is playing with fire?

The context is: I have a big number of inserts to do, that are splitted over several tables linked by foreign keys. I am trying to get good performance, and not use PL/SQL.

[EDIT] here a code sample that looks like what I'm dealing with:

```
QString query1 = "INSERT INTO table 1 (pk1_id, val) VALUES (pk1_seq.nextval, ?)"
sqlQuery->prepare(query);
sqlQuery->addBindValue(vec_of_values);
sqlQuery->execBatch();

QString query2 = "INSERT INTO table 2 (pk2_id, another_val, pk1_pk1_id) VALUES    (pk2_seq.nextval, ?, ?)"
sqlQuery->prepare(query);
sqlQuery->addBindValue(vec_of_values);

// How do I get the primary keys (hundreds of them)
// from the first insert??
sqlQuery->addBindValue(vec_of_pk1);
sqlQuery->execBatch();
```

Comment: It's not playing with fire if you only insert from one session but it's _a lot_ slower. Create a sequence with a big cache and use that.

Comment: Using `max(pk)` will not scale, will be slow and worst of all: if won't be correct if more than one session is doing that. Tom Kyte says regarding the subject of creating your own PK values: "*You can either make it correct, **or** fast **or** scalable*" (that implies you can only achieve one of those goals, never all three)

Comment: Why do you have "hundreds of PKs" if the first INSERT only creates a single row?

Comment: It is not creating a single row....hundreds of rows in one call.

Comment: Then I don't understand that language you are using... I only see a single INSERT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it's c++ using the Qt toolkit, see doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#execBatch . Maybe I should ask on a Qt forum...

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing yourself to slower performance, errors in your logic, and extra code to maintain. Oracle sequences are optimized for your specific purpose. For high DML operations you may also cache sequences:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE customers_seq CACHE 100;
```

Comment: I see. But how do I proceed in practice, I do my inserts in the first tables (keys are generated by sequences), and then I want to do the inserts in the second tables, where I need the keys from the first inserts, but how do i get them?. How should I do this efficiently?

Comment: @v3h3mental: just use `customers_seq.currval` when you insert the foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence for the master table(s)
Insert into the master table using `your_sequence.nextval`
Inserts into child (dependent) tables are done using `your_sequence.currval`

```
create table parent (id integer primary key not null);
create table child (id integer primary key not null, pid integer not null references parent(id));
create sequence parent_seq;
create sequence child_seq;

insert into parent (id) values (parent_seq.nextval);
insert into child (id, pid) values (child_seq.nextval, parent_seq.currval);
commit;
```

To explain why max(id) will not work reliably, consider the following scenario:

1. Transaction 1 retrieves max(id) + 1 (yields, say 42)
2. Transaction 1 insert a new row with id = 42
3. Transaction 2 retrieves max(id) + 1 (also yields 42, because transaction 1 is not yet committed)
4. Transaction 1 commits
5. Transcation 2 inserts a new row with id = 42
6. Transaction 2 tries to commit and gets a unique key violation

Now think about what happens when you have a **lot** of transactions doing this. You'll get a **lot** of errors. Additionally your inserts will be slower and slower, because the cost of calculating max(id) will increase with the size of the table.

Sequences *are* the only sane (i.e. correct, fast and scalable) way out of this problem.

**Edit**

If you are struck with yet another ORM which can't cope with these kind of strategy (which is supported by nearly all DBMS nowadays - even SQL Server has sequences now), then you should be able to do the following in your client code:

Retrieve the next PK value using `select parent_seq.nextval from dual` into a variable in your programming language (this is a fast, scalable and correct way to retrieve the PK value).

If you can run a `select max(id)` you can also run a `select parent_seq.nextval from dual`. In both cases just use the value obtained from that select statement.

Comment: I can work it out in a small example like this.. The problem is that I think I'm limited by the library I use (QtSql). I use batch query for the first set of insert and batch query for the second, and i am not sure I understand how to apply the scheme you described. (I am allowed only one SQL statement per exec())....

Comment: @v3h3mental: see my edit. If you are only allowed a single statement, how do you get the `max(id)`?